# How would you parse this ingredient line?

Tags: parsing, theory

I have a text area full of lines of ingredient; typically in a [quantity] [measurement] [ingredient] [additional] format.  For example, a few ingredient lines might be:

> 1 tablespoon garlic, minced
>   1 cup bell pepper, chopped

I want to be able to identify each measurement and ingredient -- how would you process this?  My line of thought was...

```
// loop thru line by line of textarea

// explode each line by the space thus line[0] would be 1, line[1] tablespoon, line[2] garlic... etc
```

Now here is my problem and I'm not sure what is efficient to do.  Do I run each line[X] thru a db search for that measurement, ingredient, etc?  But since "bell pepper" is separated by a space, I won't get a match.

```
// does line[1] appear in the measurements table?
// does line[2] appear in the ingredients table?
```

anyone else have any creative solutions?

Comment: This is tricky.  For example, instead of "1 tablespoon" they might put "1 tbsp" or even "1tbsp" or "1 tbs".  Or "1 heaping tablespoon".  Or "cup of X" rather than "1 cup X".  Unless your users are very obedient about your input standards (ha!) this is going to be extremely hard to reliably parse.  You might want to consider using AI.  In particular, NLP.  Or just have an army of moderators. :)

Comment: haha, good stuff.  I was hoping to use a combination of some parsing and team of moderators.  If the code can reduce the amount of time the moderator needs to parse an ingredient list, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your data not by space but another delimiter. For example you could do:

```
$strRecipe = "1 | tablespoon | bell pepper |  minced";
```

And then you can use:

```
$recipe = explode("|",$strRecipe);
```

Now you can access each field by: $recipe[0], $recipe[1] ETC ETC

Comment: Neat suggestion!  I wonder if users would follow suit though.  I'm assuming that users might be just copying recipes they have in email, facebook, etc. I guess, though, I could have a team of moderators to help re-parse the data.

Comment: You can have the users enter each component on a separate text box or have pre populated select boxes. That way you will always know what the inputs could be. It will be tricky to let user input all the recipe in one box as they will enter crap.

Answer (score 0):

Try `stripos()` to locate substring instead of `explode()`.

```
$mytext = "1 tablespoon garlic, minced 1 cup bell pepper, chopped"; # or any text
$keyword = "bell pepper"; # or any search term

if (stripos($mytext, $keyword) === false) {
  # not found
  ...
  }
else {
  # found
  ...
  }
```

References

- [stripos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) - case-insensitive search
- [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) - case-sensitive search

You can use `explode()` (not recommended) but than also you should separate words in your search term and look for an occurrence of first keyword in array where next keyword follows in next element of array, etc. It's unnecessary complication.